# Не считывается бинарный файл c++

Tags: c++

Не считывается (или не записывается) бинарный файл, в чем проблема?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

using namespace std;

void InputBinary(char* name);
void showStudents(char* name);

struct student {
    struct {
        char name[15];
        char surname[15];
        char patronimic[15];
    } name;
    int course;
    char group[15];
    struct {
        int mark;
        char subject[15];
    } session[8];
    double scholarship = 0;

};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UKR");
    char name[99];

    cin.getline(name, 98);
    InputBinary(name);
    showStudents(name);


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}



void InputBinary(char* name) {
    int count;
    FILE* file = fopen(name, "ab");
    cout << "Введіть кількість студентів\n";
    cin >> count;
    cin.get();
    student *ToWrite = new student[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << "Введіть Ім'я: ";
        cin.getline(ToWrite[i].name.name, 14);
        cout << "Введіть прізвище: ";
        cin.getline(ToWrite[i].name.surname, 14);
        cout << "Введіть по батькові: ";
        cin.getline(ToWrite[i].name.patronimic, 14);
        cout << "Введіть курс: ";
        cin >> ToWrite[i].course;
        cin.get();
        cout << "Введіть назву групи: ";
        cin.getline(ToWrite[i].group, 14);
        cout << "Введіть предмет та оцінку\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            scanf("%s %d", ToWrite[i].session[j].subject, &ToWrite[i].session[j].mark);
        }
        cin.get();
    }
    fwrite(ToWrite, sizeof(student), count, file);

    fclose(file);
    delete[] ToWrite;
}

void showStudents(char* name) {
    FILE* file = fopen(name, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int count = ftell(file) / sizeof(student);
    student *students = new student[count];
    fread(students, sizeof(student), count, file);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << students[i].name.surname << " " << students[i].name.name << " " << students[i].name.patronimic << endl;
        cout << "Група: " << students[i].group << endl;
        cout << "Курс: " << students[i].course << endl;
        cout << "Розмір стипендії: " << students[i].scholarship << endl;
        cout << "Оцінки за останню сесію\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            cout << students[i].session[j].subject << " : " << students[i].session[j].mark << endl;
        }
        cout << "-----------------------------\n";
    }
    fclose(file);
    delete[] students;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы становитесь на конец файла:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
```

а затем читаете:

```
fread(students, sizeof(student), count, file);
```

Вернитесь в начало файла перед чтением!